# AADB2C Custom Policies: The data type of the claim with does not match the DataType of ClaimType specified in the policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've been creating an Invitation policy on AADB2C, this is secured with a JWT as per the the [WingTipGames](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication) examples provided by Azure.

My example is slightly different because I'm using Azure Functions instead of a .NET app.

I've enabled Application Insights on my custom policy to get a bit more information on why it's failing after login. I'm successfully redirected to my social login, but after logging in it looks like it's having an issue with User creation. I'm getting this error:

```
The data type 'Boolean' of the claim with id 'verified_email' does not match the DataType 'String' of ClaimType with id 'extension_VerifiedEmail' specified in the policy.
```

Here's a snippet from my `RelyingParty`

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Invitation">
  <DisplayName>Invitation</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
  <InputTokenFormat>JWT</InputTokenFormat>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ClientSecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

This is what my `ClaimType` looks like in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`

```xml
<ClaimType Id="extension_VerifiedEmail">
  <DisplayName>Verified Email</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="verified_email" />
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="verified_email" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
  <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

This is another snippet from my Google `ClaimsProvider` in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`

```xml
<InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailFromVerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaims>
<OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" Required="true" />
...
</OutputClaims>
```

Here's the `ClaimsTransformation` mentioned in the above code

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateEmailFromVerifiedEmail" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Finally, here's a snippet from where I'm constructing the JWT that's passed over to the custom policy.

```cs
var verifiedEmailClaim = new Claim("verified_email", email);
instancePolicyClaims.Add(verifiedEmailClaim);
```

I've decoded the JWT manually and I can verify that the claim exists in the JWT called `verified_email` and the value is correct. I'm not sure what's going on or where `Boolean` is coming from in the error message mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was getting caused by some `<InputClaims>` and `<OutputClaims>` on my Google ClaimsProvider.

I added them as per the spec for WingTipGames but the document they included in the git repo was only for local accounts.

I removed the following lines and it's now working.

```xml
</CryptographicKeys>
<!-- <InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateEmailFromVerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaimsTransformations>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" />
  </InputClaims> -->
<OutputClaims>
  <!-- <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_VerifiedEmail" Required="true" /> -->
</OutputClaims>
```